# Iterator on MySQL-using objects

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I was thinking about such problem... Let's say we have a class Person:

```
   class Person {  
    private $iPersonId;
    private $sName;  
    private $sLastName;  
    private $rConn;


public function __construct($rConn, $iPersonId) {
$this->rConn = $rConn;
$this->iPersonId = $iPersonId;
}

   public function load() {
      // load name and last name using the $rConn object and $iPersonId
   }  
   }
```

And now we want to perform some actions on many people so we write a new class:

```
class People {

private $aPeople = array();

public function addPerson(Person $oPerson) {
// ...
}

public function loadPeople() {
// PROBLEM HERE //
}

}
```

And now there are two problems:
1. Person and People have the same interface for loading (function load()) but if I wanted to iterate through $aPeople in People to load their data then this would result in maaaaany queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = 1
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = 2
SELECT ......
.....
....
```

And if wanted to load 1000 then something would go boom :) .

How do I design this code for loading all the users in one query? (IN)

1. I have to keep using Dependency Injection in every Person object I add into People. It's against the DRY rule and just doesn't look well.

So dear users, what is the better way to design this code?

Comment: what's the content of `loadPeople()`?

Comment: foreach($aPeople as $oPerson)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a static method within People to load a bulk of people.
This would also require you to rewrite the constructor, or add another method to initialize the other data.

```
class Person {  
  protected $_data
  protected $rConn;


  public function __construct($rConn, $iPersonId) {
    $this->rConn = $rConn;
    $this->_data = array();
    $this->_data['id'] = $iPersonId;
  }

  public function load() {
    // load name and last name using the $rConn object and $iPersonId
  }

  // under the assumption, that $rConn is a mysqli connection
  // if not rewrite the specific section
  // also there is no injection protection or error handling in here
  // this is just a workflow example, not good code!
  public static function loadPeople($ids) {
    $res = $rConn->query("select * from people where id in (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")");
    $people = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
      $p = new People($rConn, $row['id']);
      $p->setData($row);
      $people[] = $p;
    }
    $res->free();
    return $people;
  }

  public function setData($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value {
      $this->_data[key] = $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build a service as in Symfony2 (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/service_container.html), you can just add methods. It doesn't sound right to have a "load()" on a "person". What does it load, Itself? It's also a bad practice to give your Object or Entity access to the database, this causes unwanted dependencies.

- Your Entity or Object should never have a function to load itself, bad practice. Let something else manage the Entities or Objects.
- Don't make dependencies that cause confusion, keep an object to its own purpose. A PersonEntity should never know anything about a Database Connection or EntityManager
- Build your code so that you can move it into another project without things breaking Composer. http://getcomposer.org/

example as how I would do it in symfony2

```php
class PeopleService
{
  private $em;

  /**
   * @param EntityManager $em
   */
  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $id
   * @return Person
   */
  public function loadPerson($id)
  {
    // do something and return 1 person
    return $this->em->find('MyBundleNamspace:Person', $id);
  }

  /**
   * @return array of Person objects
   */
  public function loadPeople()
  {
    // do something and return an array with persons
  }
}
```